# Linux ou GNU/Linux?

Tags: linux, terminologia, sistema-operacional

Sempre houve uma polêmica com relação ao nome do Sistema Operacional Linux. Uns creem se chamar apenas Linux, outros o denominam GNU/Linux. Afinal, existe uma forma correta de se referenciar a este Sistema Operacional?

Comment: Olha o meu eu chamo de Escaminosflau, mas vai de cada um e nivel de intimidade com ele.

Comment: lembrando isso foi uma brincadeira

Comment: Eu gosto e apoio perguntas de terminologia aqui, desde que sejam voltadas a programação e desenvolvimento (escopo do nosso site), então votei pra fechar, pois não é o caso, no entanto já tem algumas respostas úteis. Não leve a mal ok? Outras perguntas de terminologia desde que do ambiente de desenvolvimento me parecem ok então fique a vontade pra perguntar :)

Comment: Tranquilo @GuilhermeNascimento, sem problemas. Deveria ter feito essa pergunta no chat. Agora, qual que é o procedimento mais adequado para encerrar esta questão?

Comment: Pode esperar, talvez ela seja fechada ou não, vai depender dos votos, se votarem pra manter aberta talvez signifique que a comunidade aceite bem este tipo de pergunta (não estou falando de terminologia, mas sim sobre diferença de ambientes), vai mesmo da comunidade. Se mais votarem pra fechar ela vai ser publica ainda e vai poder ganhar votos com ela, mas ninguém mais vai poder responder, então é só esperar :D

Comment: para o pessoal(GNU) que fez os demais programas base em torno do kernel(LINUX) é importante deixar a sua marca, para os demais mortais basta apenas um nome que referencie toda essa liberdade que é o software livre

Comment: Logo logo o GNU vai ter seu próprio kernel: https://xkcd.com/1508/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux é apenas o núcleo (*kernel*) do Sistema Operacional, responsável por realizar a comunicação entre hardware (impressoras, monitores, teclado, etc) e software.

Já GNU (que é um acrônimo recursivo para `GNU's not Unix`) é um projeto desenvolvido por Richard Stallman em 1983 que tem por objetivo criar um Sistema Operacional completo apenas com free software. O projeto GNU foi o responsável por desenvolver diversos programas utilizados no Sistema Operacional GNU/Linux, como o GNU C Compiler (gcc), o editor de texto Emacs, diversos programas que você usa diarimente no terminal, entre muitas outras utilidades.

Então temos que Linux é o núcleo de um Sistema Operacional, não muito útil em si só para usuários finais, e os programas do projeto GNU são os outros programas que, em conjunto com o Linux, compõe o Sistema Operacional GNU/Linux.

A ideia inicial de Richard Stallman era fazer com que o próprio GNU desenvolvesse um núcleo para o Sistema Operacional, mas como isso nunca foi feito (até hoje não existe uma versão estável do núcleo do GNU), quando Linus Torvalds lançou o Linux em 1991 ele foi incorporado aos programas GNU e distribuído como um Sistema Operacional completo.

No final das contas, nenhuma das partes concorda em como o Sistema Operacional deveria ser chamado, e o nome `Linux` é o mais utilizado apenas por ser mais simples do que `GNU/Linux`.

Vale a pena ler o que os dois principais desenvolvedores nessa história têm a dizer sobre o assunto:

Richard Stallman em uma [entrevista à ZNET](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=106548) em 2005:

> Linux was not designed with the goal of liberating cyberspace, and the motives for Linux would not have given us the whole GNU/Linux system.
>
> Today tens of millions of users are using an operating system that was developed so they could have freedom — but they don’t know this, because they think the system is Linux and that it was developed by a student “just for fun’.”

E a [opinião do Torvalds](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/comp.os.linux.misc/Cm15HxjDGRs/su3OHyLUgXcJ):

> Umm, this discussion has gone on quite long enough, thank you very much.
>
> It doesn’t really *matter* what people call Linux, as long as credit is given where credit is due (on both sides).  Personally, I’ll very much continue to call it “Linux”

Answer (score 6):

A pergunta já responde isso. Se os maiores especialistas no assunto [não se entendem](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=linux%20gnu%20linux%20debate) sobre isto, não é uma resposta no SOpt que vai dizer qual é o correto.

Não parece haver dúvidas que o *kernel* é só Linux. O sistema como um todo pra mim também é Linux, mas a FSF acha que é GNU/Linux. Na prática só os fanáticos pela FSF chamam o Linux de GNU/Linux. O fato é que isto não muda a vida de ninguém e só paranoicos realmente gastam mais que alguns segundos sobre o tema.

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU/Linux_naming_controversy)

Comment: +1 pela franqueza `só paranoicos realmente gastam mais que alguns segundos sobre o tema` boa...rsrsrrs

Comment: Também conhecidos como GNU/Chatos. :)

Answer (score 0):

O GNU certamente faz parte da construção do sistema Operacional Linux mas não acho que deve levar todo crédito.

O Kernel Linux em si não veio de um pacote GNU, se não fosse pelo kernel Linux, não haveria nenhum sistema operacional GNU, acho que cada distribuição Linux deve ser chamada pelo seu nome como Red Hat, Debian, entre outros e não GNU/Linux.

Na minha opinião,se você fizer uma distribuição Linux você colocará o nome como GNU/Linux ? Certamente não.

Fica a dica :)